# How to get substring keys on firebase?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with firebase on pyhon3. I wanted to know if there's a way I can check if a substring is present in the firebase keys. For e.g. if I have a string 'he', and I have keys in my firebase for 'hell' and 'hello'. I can perform a get for 'he', but how can I get the others as well. And i dont want to get the entire parent and search on python as it is a fairly large database.
How can I go about to get them? I know this is not how firebase is designed. But remodeling will take a lot of time. So can it be done, and if so how?

Comment: Hi Hamza, I've added a generic answer for substring within string checks with Python. However, I can give you a more explicit answer if you can provide more information and code. Thanks.

Comment: In my firebase I have a node 'tech', whose children are a list of different web technologies used in websites. Such as Google Analytics, AWS etc. and each of them have children who are websites that use this technology. So I want to figure out a way that if I search for lets say google, I can find all the keys which have google such as google analytics, google dns, google adsense etc. 
through this I can get the google analytics node from my db: db_info = fb.get('/tech/GoogleAnalytics')

Answer (score 1):

Try using `in` like this:

```
>>> x = 'hello'
>>> y = 'll'
>>> y in x
True
```

So if you have a value you can assign, and you know what you want to check against, this is the easiest way to go about this in Python.

Comment: Thanks for that. Probably should have been more clear but I actually meant finding the substrings on firebase's side. I can get 'he', need to figure out how to get 'hell', 'hello'.